# How to build Models for (possibly) polymorphic relationship with Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, database-schema, polymorphic-associations, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a question regarding Eloquent ORM -- in this case, specifically being used with Laravel 4. I have had no problem using it to run basic queries and relationships, but I'm recently stumped on this somewhat unique scenario/schema:

I have three tables. Their structures are currently this:

```
post
    id - int
    post_type - enum(ARTICLE, QUOTE)
    user_id - int
    created_at - timestamp
    updated_at - timestamp

post_type_article
    id - int
    post_id - int
    title - varchar
    summary - varchar
    url - varchar

post_type_quote
    id - int
    post_id = int
    author = varchar
    quote = text
```

At the end of this, I would like to just run one query/function using Eloquent ORM and get all posts and their respective data regardless of post_type.

I'd really like to hear some feedback on this (my relationships, what my models should be). From my understanding, this is probably a polymorphic relation. Here are/were my Models, but I am new to this, and am not sure if this the right direction or not:

Model: Post.php:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function postType()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

Model: PostTypeArticle.php:

```
<?php

class PostTypeArticle extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = FALSE;
    protected $table = 'post_type_article';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Post', 'post_type');
    }
}
```

Model: PostTypeQuote.php:

```
<?php

class PostTypeQuote extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = FALSE;
    protected  $table = 'post_type_quote';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Post', 'post_type');
    }

}
```

Maybe since I'm using ENUM as a foreign key I need to explicitly specify that? Anyways, hopefully you can spot my confusion and point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help in advanced while I get the hang of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would be brave about this one and condense the types tables into one: post_types:

**posts**

```
    id - int (auto-increment)
    user_id - int (unsigned)
    created_at - timestamp
    updated_at - timestamp
```

**post_types**

```
    id - int (auto-increment)
    type - int //or varchar
    post_id - int (unsigned)
    title - varchar
    summary- varchar
    url - varchar
    author - varchar
    quote - text
```

Make most of the fields in the **post_types** table nullable (your homework)

**Post.php**

```
<?php

  class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function postType()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('Posttype'); //or hasMany()
    }

  }
```

**Posttype.php**

```
<?php

  class Posttype extends Eloquent {
    protected  $table = 'post_types';

    public function post()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Post'); 
    }

  }
```

**Getting Results**

```
$posts = Post::with('postType')->get(); //eager-loading
```

**OR**

```
$post = Post::find(1)->postType; //One post
```

**Homework**

1. Use validation to ensure the fields you need in the database are all there in user input
2. Decide where to run your **if statements** to determine whether you are dealing with an **article** or **quote**